# Solving PDE using the Fourier transform technique

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-transform

I was trying to solve this PDE, but I haven't been able to fully solve the exercise:
$$\partial_t f(x,t) = 2t\partial_{xx}^2f(x,t) + \delta(t^2-6t+5)\frac{e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} }{\sqrt{2\pi}}, f(x,0) = \frac{e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} }{\sqrt{2\pi}} $$
I started by noticing that $\delta(t^2-6t+5) = \frac{1}{4}[\delta(t-5)+\delta(t-1)]$
So I solved the pde for $t < 1$, which reduces to the simpler form:
$$\partial_t f(x,t) = 2t\partial_{xx}^2f(x,t) $$
Using the Fourier transform, namely: $$f(x,t) = 1 / \sqrt{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\hat{f}(k,t)e^{ikx}dk, \hat{f}(k,t) = 1 / \sqrt{2\pi} \int f(x',t)e^{-ikx'}dx'$$
one easily gets to the easy ODE:
$$\frac{d}{dt}\hat{f}(k,t) = -2k^2t\hat{f}(k,t) \Rightarrow \hat{f}(k,t) = \hat{f}(k,0)e^{-k^2t^2}$$
Now I need to compute $$ \hat{f}(k,0) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int f(x',0)e^{-ikx'}dx' = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int e^{-x'^2/2}e^{-ikx'}dx'$$
Using the formula for the Gaussian integral I got:
$$ \hat{f}(k,0) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-k^2/2}$$
Therefore I finally obtain, anti-transforming:
$$f(x,t) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int e^{ikx}e^{-k^2(1/2+t^2)} $$
Which is again easily solvable using the well known formula $\int e^{i\beta y}e^{-ay^2}dy =\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}e^{-\frac{\beta^2}{4a}}$. The result is:
$$ f(x,t) = \frac{1}{2\pi(1+2t^2)}e^{-\frac{x^2}{4(1/2 + t^2)}}$$
I checked and it was all ok.
Now the challenging part begins: I tried to consider the equation for $t \in ]1,5[$. The PDE reduces to:
$$ \partial_t f(x,t) = 2t\partial_{xx}^2f(x,t) + \frac{1}{4}\delta(t-1)\frac{e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} }{\sqrt{2\pi}} $$
I used the Fourier transform again and got:
$$ \frac{d}{dt}\hat{f}(k,t) = -2k^2t\hat{f}(k,t) + \frac{1}{4}\delta(t-1)\frac{1}{2\pi} \int e^{-x^2/2} e^{ikx}dx \tag{1}$$
which leads to:
$$  \frac{d}{dt}\hat{f}(k,t) = -2k^2t\hat{f}(k,t) + \frac{1}{4 \sqrt{2\pi}}\delta(t-1)e^{-k^2/2}$$
I tried to solve the ODE like this (making use of the sifting property in the last equality):
$$ \hat{f}(k,t) = \hat{f}(k,0)e^{-k^2t^2} + \frac{1}{4 \sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{0}^{t} e^{-k^2(t-t')^2}\delta(t'-1)dt' = \hat{f}(k,0)e^{-k^2t^2} + \frac{1}{4 \sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-k^2(t-1)^2} $$
This would lead me to:
$$ \hat{f}(k,t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-k^2/2}e^{-k^2t^2} + \frac{1}{4\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-k^2(t-1)^2}$$
Now using the anti-transform would mean solving an impossible integral. I can assume my procedure was wrong from the start, or maybe I wrongly solved the ODE $(1)$ which again wouldn't surprise me. If someone could help me and clarify how to solve this PDE for $t > 1$, I'd be no far from grateful\
P.S. I realized after @Winther's comment that I blindly assumed the integral was wrt $x$. Since I am integrating wrt $k$, I would obtain the following solution, deriving from the sum of two Gaussian integrals, like the ones before:
$$ f(x,t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi(1+2t^2)}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2+4t^2}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{64\pi(t-1)^2}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{4(t-1)^2}}$$
Nevertheless, the solution for $t>1$ is, according to my professor (doesn't tell me how to get this result though):
$$ f(x,t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi(1+2t^2)}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2+4t^2}} + f_1(x,t)$$, where $$ f_1(x,t) = \frac{1}{4\sqrt{(4(t^2-1)+2)\pi}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{4(t^2-1)+2}}$$
whereas for $t>5$ the solution is:
$$f(x,t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi(1+2t^2)}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2+4t^2}} + f_1(x,t) + f_2(x,t) $$, where
$$f_2(x,t) = \frac{1}{4}\frac{1}{\sqrt{(4(t^2-5)+2)\pi} }e^{-\frac{x^2}{4(t^2-5)+2}} $$

Comment: "Now using the anti-transform would mean solving an impossible integral" Assuming you did it correctly then this function is just a sum of two terms that both are on the form $e^{-ak^2}$. If you know how to take the Fourier transform of a general gaussian then you can use this to take the inverse transform. Note that the fact that $a$ ($=(1/2 + t^2$ for ther first term and $=(t-1)^2$ for the second term) depends on $t$ is irrelevant for taking the inverse transform (which is wrt $x$).

Comment: Did you mean $\partial_{xx}$ or $\partial_x^2$ rather than $\partial_{xx}^2$?

Comment: $$\frac{\partial^2 f(x,t)}{\partial x^2}$$. You made me realized the integral is wrt $k$ not $x$, so I would get two gaussian integrals.

Comment: @Gonçalo you’re right, the right formula is indeed: $$  y(0)e^{\int -2k^2tdt}+\frac{1}{4\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-k^2/2}\int_{0}^{t}e^{k^2t’^2}\delta(t’-1)dt’$$ which gives the correct solution. Problem’s still there. It just changes the second Gaussian integral to something like this $$\alpha e^{-\frac{x^2}{4(t^2+1)}}$$, which is still far from the expected solution.

Comment: Better take fourier tranform of your advisor solution and post it in the question and compare it with the solution you are getting and reverse engineer to find your problem.

Comment: @Gonçalo I have a question, a doubt to be more precise: in a recent exercise we were solving a PDE, containing a $\delta(t)G(x)$ term. And everybody agrees that for $t \ne 0$ the term vanishes. In this case instead, I wasn't paying much attention and just said that for $t < 1$ the two delta functions vanish, for $t > 1, t < 5$ we need not consider the $\delta(t-5)$ term and for $t > 5$ we need not consider the $\delta(t-5)$ term.

Comment: But, actually, the delta terms don't vanish only when we consider an interval of the form  $I = [t_i-\epsilon, t + \epsilon], t_1 = 1, t_2 = 5$ as $\epsilon \to 0^+$. So basically there's no way that our PDE could reduce itself to those forms where for example an additional term is added,such as $1/4\delta(t-1)f(x,0)$ or for $t>5$ the additional term $1/4\delta(t-5)f(x,0)$. Wouldn't those additional terms just vanish since we are in the case $t \ne t_i$ both for $t > 1$ and for $t >5$. Why do we need to add those pieces to the solutions?

Comment: Couldn't be clearer. Thank you again

Answer (score 1):

I think comments helped you with your problem but i see you are having to do lot of integrals to get the answer. So here is a thought for simplification.

Solve $$\partial_u g(x,u) = \partial^2_x g(x,u)$$

and now form the equation $f(x,t) = g(x,t^2)$

$$\partial_t f(x,t) = \partial_t g(x,t^2) = 2t \partial_u g(x,u) |_{u=t^2}$$

$$2t \partial_x^2 f(x,t)  = 2t \partial^2_x g(x,t^2) =   2t \times \partial^2_x g(x,u)|_{u=t^2}$$

Hence $f(x,t) = g(x,t^2)$ is your solution.

So i think its enough to solve for
$$\partial_u g(x,u) = \partial^2_x g(x,u)$$

As an example: $g(x,u) = e^{x} e^{t}$ is a solution and hence $$f(x,t) = e^{x} e^{t^2}$$ is a solution but does not satisfy boundary conditions.

See if these help writing it in simple form.